# Relation between group $k$-transitivity and primitivity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $X$ be a finite set and $n=|X|$. Let $G$ be $k$-transitive group on $X$ for some $k$ such that $1\leq k\leq n$. If $G$ is also primitive, does this necessarily imply that $k>1$? My book says yes. I am not sure  how to prove it.

I know that $G$ being primitive means that, for all $x\in G$, $G_x$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$. How does this property together with $k$-transitivity imply that $k>1$? How should I be thinking about this?

**Edit:**

I did not express the problem correctly. I have to prove that $k>1$ together with $k$-transitivity of $G$ imply that $G$ is primitive.

Comment: No. For example the group $\langle (1,2,3) \rangle$ with $n=3$ is primitive but not 2-transitive.

Comment: How about this: if a $G$ is $k$-transitive and $k>1$, then $G$ is primitive. Does this hold?

Comment: Yes that is true. It's a standard result and not very difficult to prove.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Last question: should I be using induction?

Comment: No, you can show for example, that $(k+1)$-transitivity implies $k$-transitivity (which is basically trivial), and then you show that $2$-transitive implies primitive (which is a little exercise).